How does the wormhole between 2 parallel universes inside a black hole work? (Penrose diagram)
There is a theory that inside of an eternal Schwarzschild black hole two astronauts (assuming they are immortal) from two parallel universes could meet and it is show on a Penrose diagram for an eternal Schwarzschild black hole.

The diamond shaped areas are two universes. To the sides there are spacial infinities and up and down there are time infinities. There are two triangles in the middle. The upper one is a black hole and the lower on is a white because it's the mathematical opposite of a black hole. The zig-zaged lines are singularities.
Any mass can only move within a 45° cone up, as this is the future and you cannot travel backwards in time. Any mass can only move in this way, because if you sent a pulse of light and took a picture of it at regular inrervals you would get a cone at a 45° angle (as show on the picture) and no mass can move at a greater speed than the speed of light, so it cannot move outside the cone.

If time moves in one direction the the upper cone is the future cone meaning anything you do or travel to has to be contained in that cone. The lower cone is the past cone, meaning anything that could affect you has to be contained in that cone.
Because it's impossible to move at a greater speed than light (at a greater angle than that of the light cone), it is impossible to travel to the parallel Universe directly. However it is possible to meet inside the horizon of a black hole. But that raised some questions.
My questions are:

What determines what parallel universe a black hole is connected to? Is each black hole connected to a different universe? Is it determined by its mass?

If what parallel universe a black hole is connected to, is determined by its mass, how sensitive is it? Is it so sensitive that in a very short time Hawking radiation or gluon fluctuations can change what universe said black hole is connected to?

If what parallel universe a back hole is connected to is determined by its mass, what if an electron was about to be connected to a parallel universe but the black hole's mass changed enough to be connected to another universe what happens to this electron?

If two astronauts can meet inside a black hole then doesn't that mean mass in one or both universes increased breaking one of the most basic laws of our universe?


I've looked everywhere and asked many people but no one knew the answer. I would be very grateful if someone could answer.

The idea of another Universe is just an artifact of the Penrose diagram's shape, not something physical. Spacetime is completely-valid under the common black hole metrics up to the singularity without requiring another Universe. Additionally trying to enumerate "other parallel Universes" is ill-defined at best. (Welcome to Physics SE, by the way. I think you should start by asking how to interpret the parallel Universe first, then asking about how you determine "which" parallel Universe each black hole connects to.)

I voted to reopen. While OP did phrase the question in many different subquestions (which gives the impression of an unfocused question), they are all closely related. The core of the question is merely to understand how a black hole connects to different "parallel universes" in a Penrose diagram, and the different subquestions simply approach the same topic from slightly different perspectives.

In the Schwarzschild solution, the black hole is connected to both universes (hence why the two astronauts can meet). We assume the astronaut mass is negligible compared to the black hole, so the black hole mass doesn't change (even so, energy only needs to be conserved locally, not globally, and it is not conserved in the whole universe). The presence of charge can drastically change the Penrose diagram, but so can the assumption that the black hole was formed through stellar collapse instead of being eternal: the Penrose diagram you showed assumes an eternal black hole, while a black hole arising from stellar collapse only has a single universe (no parallel universe this time).
Shortly, you shouldn't take the parallel universe idea too seriously: it is way too sensitive to the metric and in practice we don't expect the parallel universe to be there. If you want to take it seriously, then the black hole connects to both universes and if you turn on charge the picture gets way more complicated.

Your comment cleared up a lot, however I made a mistake by asking what would happen to an electron. I should have asked about a neutron to keep the charge neutral. In my question I ment what if a very small particle was "cut" by the change in the universe connected.

@Mateusz It isn't possible to have a change in the universe(s) connected.

@Níckolas Alves - Why wouldn't it, the astronaut from one universe could be twice as massive as the astronaut from the other universe, so he would make his version of the black hole heavier than the other if he jumps in, so if the assumption that the two connected universes can only stay connected if the black hole has the same mass on both sides that would destroy the entanglement, although I don't know where this assumption comes from. In that case the Schwarzschild metric won't work anyways though since it assumes eternal and constant mass.

If we assume the parallel universe is just a mirrored coordinate reflection of the regular universe then it is of course impossible to have two different astronauts on both sides, but if we introduce spin the parallel universe is no longer symmetric to the regular universe, so I don't know if that's the right interpretation since Schwarzschild is a limit of Kerr.

@Yukterez destroying the connection would violate causality: what happens in the event horizon in one of the parallel universes cannot affect the other. The way I think about it is that the whole spacetime is already determined from the start. If the connection could be destroyed, it simply wouldn't have existed in the first place. For example, if we add astronauts to the Schwarzschild solution, we spoiled spherical symmetry and the parallel universe probably does not occur in the exact solution anymore

If you consider the astronauts as moving on top of the spacetime without affecting it, then they cannot destroy or construct any new connections (this is the point of view I took in the answer). If you consider them as affecting the spacetime, then the Schwarzschild solution does not apply and I find it likely you never had a parallel universe to begin with. In fact, you probably can't even draw a Penrose diagram anymore due to lack of symmetry

@Níckolas Alves - I agree, except with the part where you couldn't draw a Penrose diagram: you could either have spherical shells falling into the black hole to preserve spherical symmetry, or take a slice like it is done with Kerr where due to lack of spherical symmetry most Penrose diagrams use polar slices where θ=0 (then you can fly though the ring, while at the equatorial slice you can't).

@Yukterez Fair enough
